# Node.js 'request' module wrapper with optional params - how to write this more concise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a wrapper around [node-request](/questions/tagged/node-request):

```
var RequestWrapper = function(client, method, type, uuid, body, callback) {

    callback = callback || body || uuid

    // Let's get this looking a little cleaner!
    body = (typeof body === 'object') ? body : uuid
    body = (typeof body === 'object') ? body : undefined

    var uri = urljoin(config.baseUrl, type, (typeof uuid === 'string') ? uuid : "")
    var params = request.initParams(uri, {
        body: body
    }, callback)

    params.method = method

    params.json = true

    request(params, function(error, response) {
        response = new UsergridResponse(response)
        params.callback(error, response)
    })
}

module.exports = RequestWrapper
```

I'm supporting four RESTful methods, with optional arguments like so:

```
wrapper(client, 'GET', 'pets', cb) // returns an array of pets
wrapper(client, 'GET', 'pets', '<uuid>', cb) // returns a specific pet
wrapper(client, 'PUT', 'pets', '<uuid>', cb) // updates the specified pet
wrapper(client, 'POST', 'pets', { body: {} }, cb) // creates a new pet
wrapper(client, 'DELETE', 'pets', '<uuid>', cb) // deletes the specified pet
```

My RequestWrapper works like it is, but I really dislike the way I'm checking for optional `body` param and optional uuid param. I managed to get `callback` all pretty looking -- is there a way I can do this for `body` too?

Comment: Are you using ES6/2015?

Comment: @Shashank yeah I am, though I'd like to see this in a non-ES6 solution too.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because it is about how to write working code _differently_.

Comment: Off topic: Regarding your question you just deleted, you'd be much better off using something like this to get/test deep properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: @Mathletics yeah - deleted it because I realized I was being a knob. I misunderstood their function name - that one is ONLY for functions. I want to do it for properties, so need to rethink how to ask. Related: https://github.com/letsgetrandy/brototype/issues/38#issuecomment-159378582. Thanks for your insight though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this many parameters, use an options hash.

```
var RequestWrapper = function(opts) {
    var uri = urljoin(config.baseUrl, opts.type, (typeof opts.uuid === 'string') ? opts.uuid : "")
    var params = request.initParams(uri, {
      body: opts.body
    }, opts.callback)
/* etc */
```

---

in ES6 you can use destructuring to make this even cleaner.

```
var RequestWrapper = function(opts) {
    let {client, method, type, uuid = '', body, callback} = opts; // default for uuid
/* etc */
```

Comment: This requires me to pass an options object to the method though right? Would prefer not to do that.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to manage that many ordered params, but ok.

Comment: I suppose you're right  Also of note though, uuid isn't the problem I'd like to solve, it's body. So I can do the same thing, but I still have to check multiple properties to see if body is the correct one.

Comment: The other option would be to break up the requests by type, creating `index`, `show`, `edit`, etc functions that take fewer params. It would also look way less goofy when called (IMO).

Comment: No, `body` would always be `opts.body`. You pass it like `RequestWrapper({body: {whatever: {}})` so you don't have to inspect it. Or if you do, it's just `if (opts.body)` (objects are truthy so you know a `body` was passed.)

Comment: Yeah, which means I'm stuck passing an object. Trying to be as consistent as possible to [tag:node-request] which supports both. I'll have to move the ordered params up a level and do the checking further down the chain. Not a big deal, but definitely cleaner.

Comment: _Trying to be as consistent as possible to node-request_ I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: `request` supports ordered params: `request(uri, options, cb)` or an object `request({uri: url, body: body, headers: headers}, cb)`. Trying to build this wrapper with that same structure in mind so that this can be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: So take a hash and a callback (2 params) so that it matches theirs.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you want but you could try using [rest parameters](http://es6-features.org/#RestParameter) in combination with [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Unfortunately rest parameters are an ES6 language feature so you may need to use Babel or the `--harmony` flag.

```
var RequestWrapper = function(client, method, type, ...opts) {
  const isType = (t) => (x) => typeof x === t,
        uuid = opts.find(isType('string')) || '',
        body = opts.find(isType('object')),
        callback = opts.find(isType('function'))
  // . . .
}
```

Working with it as an array makes it slightly cleaner and rest parameters are nice syntax sugar for automatically converting tailing arguments to arrays. In ES5, you could `slice` the `arguments` from index 3 and work with it that way.

To get even fancier with function mapping and [fail-soft destructuring](http://es6-features.org/#FailSoftDestructuring):

```
const firstOptOfType = (t) => opts.find((opt) => typeof opt === t),
      [uuid = '', body, callback] = ['string', 'object', 'function']
                                      .map(firstOptOfType)
```